# Can not seem to get expr substr to work

Tags: bash, scripting, shell-scripting

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
[ /jlr/sub/libexec/vmr-staging ] $ expr substr "onetwothree" 1 4
expr: syntax error
```

I got the syntax from https://stackoverflow.com/a/220464/1150847

Comment: which OS du you use? substr is a non standard extention. The came be achieved with cut: echo "onetwothree"  | cut -c 1-3

Comment: I am developing in OS X, Production is CentOS, cut worked! Please post it as an answer and I will check it off =]

Comment: Id love to know why this was down voted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substr operation is a non standard extension and not supported on all OSes (probably linux only). The same be achieved with cut:

```
echo "onetwothree" | cut -c 1-3
```